# Get realtime values from top command in linux into my program

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I have a daemon in ruby and I am trying to execute a bash command and get its output into the program. I am able to use the backtick feature in ruby to execute a bash command like `ls -a`. But since `top` command is real time, I am not able to get the output of the command into my program. Help me.

Why I need real time data is because I am trying to monitor all processes and kill it if it's memory limit is reached or something. I don't want to do `top -bn 1`

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'daemons'

 options = {
   :backtrace => true,
   :app_name => 'limits_logger',
   :log_dir => '/home/charizard/',
   :log_output => true
 }

 Daemons.daemonize(options)

 puts "#{Time.now} - started #{self}."

 puts %x{ top -b }
```

Comment: from 'man top': top -n interations

Comment: Use `ulimit` to provide a maximum allowable memory usage when you start the process, and let the shell kill it if that limit is reached.

Comment: Actually I want to get notified if the limit is reached. Not just kill it.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want to do with the data, but parsing `top` is probably not a good solution. It's not meant to be machine-readable. All the data that top provides is available via much more programmer-friendly mechanisms:

- You can get information about all processes via the [`/proc`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) filesystem.
- You can use the [`ps`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ps.htm) command to query individual processes, or get various data about all processes.
- There are various Ruby process list interrogation libraries, like [SysUtils](http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/610/1566/sys_proctable.html), which provide a Ruby API for Linux process list interrogation.

Everything is available via `/proc`, and most other tools/APIs are sitting on top of that.

In any case, I wouldn't try to parse top's output.

Answer (score 0):

```
IO.foreach("|top -b") { |line| puts line }
```